# Can you solve this Lagrange differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can i found the solution for this: 
solve this using **Lagrange** method **(differential equation)**: 
$$\color{red}{y=2y'x+y^3}$$
***Hint:*** $$\color{#00F}{y^3 \equiv y'''}$$

Can you explain the method?

This is a capture for this example with solution. 
[image]

### **$$\color{#00F}{Translation:}$$**

**Example:**
Find the general solution for this differential equation

### **$$\color{#F00}{y=2px+p^3}$$**

**Solution:**
This equation is a differential Lagrange equation, by integrate the 02 (two) parts we obtain:

### **$$\color{#080}{p=\frac{dy}{dx}=2p+2x\frac{dp}{dx}+3p^2\frac{dp}{dx}}$$**

Comment: The equation in red is separable.

Comment: In your differential equation, does $y^3$ denote $\frac{d^3y}{dy^3}$ or $y\cdot y\cdot y$?

Comment: **$y^3$** denote **$\frac{d^3y}{dy^3}$**

Comment: Where is the solution?

Comment: @Bitrex OP says that $y^3$ is the third derivative.

Comment: If $y^3$ denotes the third derivative, then I don't think the solution is very simple.

Comment: @Amzoti I'm not sure, can you obtain the same solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given (I think there is an issue in the hint):

$$\tag 1 y = 2y' x + y^3, y^3 \equiv (y')^3$$

If we let $p = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$, we can rewrite $(1)$ as:

$$\tag 2 y = 2px + p^3$$

Differentiating $(2)$ wrt $x$ yields:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = p = 2p + 2 x \dfrac{dp}{dx} + 3 p^2 \dfrac{dp}{dx}$$

This reduces to:

$$\tag 3 3p^2\frac{dp}{dx} + 2x\frac{dp}{dx} + p = 0$$

Solving $(3)$ yields four solutions as:

$$p(x) = \pm ~\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sqrt{\pm ~\sqrt{c_1+x^2}-x}$$

From our initial substitution, we have $p = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$, so we can write:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \pm ~\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sqrt{\pm ~\sqrt{c_1+x^2}-x}$$

We can solve these four (it is possible that not all four satisfy the ODE) for $y(x)$ by rearranging and integrating. For example:

$$\int dy = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \int \sqrt{~-\sqrt{c_1+x^2}-x}~~dx $$

where $c_1$ is a constant.

Comment: I can understand that!